# Grails g:select no selection

Tags: grails, enums, gsp

I have the following combobox:

```
<g:select name="ticketType" from="${app.domain.enums.TicketType?.values()}"
                              keys="${app.domain.enums.TicketType.values() }"
                              value="${ticketInstance?.ticketType}"
                              noSelection="${['null': 'Select One...']}"
                    />
```

I've setup the following constraint for ticketType in command object

```
ticketType nullable: true, blank:true
```

TicketType is a very simple enum:

```
    public enum TicketType {
        QUESTION, SUPPORT, MAINTENANCE, NEW_FUNCTIONALITY, MALFUNCTION
}
```

And every time I don't setup some value for ticketType in my GSP I get the following error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.coming.enums.TicketPriority'
```

It's like in case of no selection g:select sets the value for "null" (string).

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show the code of your `g:select` ...

Comment: @aiolos Sorry - there was some error in formatting. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rather than using the 'null' literal, have you tried using an empty string as your noSelection attribute?  e.g. `noSelection="${['':'Select One...']}"`?  This may do a proper conversion to a true null value during data binding.

Comment: That's how I usually do it but it didn't work. So I played with different options. In the mean time I've changed some code in controllers and services, and return noSelection to noSelection="${['':'Select One...']}" and now it works. Gremlins :)

Answer (score 2):

As your error says - you do have a string in your `noSelection`. This can't be converted to any of your enum values.

Remove the quotation marks of your `null` and it should work (it works for me with grails 2.0):

```
<g:select name="ticketType" from="${app.domain.enums.TicketType?.values()}"
                          keys="${app.domain.enums.TicketType.values() }"
                          value="${ticketInstance?.ticketType}"
                          noSelection="${[null: 'Select One...']}"/>
```

Comment: I've tried that allready and it's still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: g:select ends up producing HTML, so it doesn't make any difference the quotations around null, since it will produce value="null" anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Under Rails 3.3.x, no variation of providing the "null" value worked. In the end, I resolved it by adding this line in to the controller+action before doing any use of the params:

```
// convert "null" strings to REAL nulls
params.account.each { it.value = (it.value == 'null' ? null : it.value) }
```

After that, the following worked fine:

```
account.properties = params.account
```